# Preview-latex background color

Tags: emacs, auctex, preview

I'm using AUCTeX + preview-latex to preview math formulas. In addition, I'm using the zenburn color scheme, which has a dark background. Unfortunately, the rendered math previews have a white background, which looks very ugly.

How is it possible to change the default background color in the rendered math formulas?

Comment: It would help if you link to the color scheme you use. Is it https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default settings of preview-latex should ensure that the image background is either transparent or set to the background color of the editor area. If you always get white backgrounds, have a look at the AUCTeX option *Preview Appearance > Preview Reference Face > Background*. Maybe it's set to *white*. In this case, simply uncheck the corresponding checkbox and save the settings. Otherwise, try to set an explicit background color value to check whether this option actually causes the problem.

[image]

Comment: How do we get to this menu? I'm using spacemacs

Comment: @ae0709 Inside emacs, run command `customize-group` and choose `AUCTeX`.