# Auctex previews with dark theme

Tags: auctex, preview

I am using auctex (last version from repositories) with emacs in a ubuntu 18.04 machine. I would like to customize emacs with a dark theme to reduce eye strain. When I do that, latex previews are shown with white background and a very light grey font. [image: this is a sample of preview]
I would like to customize this and choose a dark background with white fonts.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Manual has an entry [Change the color of the preview background](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex.html#Simple-customization) also there is an old [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52539/preview-latex-background-color) related to fonts

Comment: @KJO Ah! That's the point. Nice catch!

Comment: @KJO, as there is no news from the OP, I suggest you either answer or mark it as a duplicate, as you see fit.

Comment: @gusbrs agree it is potential duplicate of similar questions, however as you pinpointed before this is not exactly the same requirement hence my link to manual, which may help others with desire to change preview background rather than font.

Comment: @KJO I haven't delved as much as you into the issue. But, if you think so, how about you answer then? As I mentioned in my previous comment: "as you see fit". Of course, if you'd like to.

Comment: @KJO Btw, I do believe the question you linked here is the culprit. In my tests here, the previews are rendered with the same background color as my theme, fitting quite well. I only questioned your previous duplicate flag, because the particular question you had chosen was about fontification, rather than the preview background proper. So, I didn't mean to send you mixed signals. Your research effort here is appreciated.

Comment: @gusbrs I have not checked suggestions (am moderating on another site) so did not feel qualified to answer, If you have tested what works then please answer I can up vote and OP can accept.

Comment: I had similar issue. It turned out to be the gs version. New emacs seems to be geared towards gs > 9.27. I had 9.26 on my machine. Once updated to 9.50 problem was solved. Till then a workaround I used was setting the background of `preview-reference-face` to gray40 or something. (@gusbrs, this one is not a duplicate BTW, it's about foreground. The other question is about background.)